# Save a graph on a cluster

Tags: r, graph, cluster-computing

I am using the R package **Related** on a cluster. The workload manager is Slurm and I upload on the cluster the sbacth script and an Rscript.

**Related** has a command named `compareestimators()` which generates a graph directly. I need to get this graph but I don't know how to do it. Is it possible to save it in a file ?

[related comparestimator() output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04KSC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using functions like `pdf()` or `png()` allow you to create and save plots that normally appear in a/the viewer into external files, e.g. something like this

```
png("figures/figure1.png", width=5, height=7, res=500, units="in")
compareestimators(...)
dev.off()
```

Comment: If that answers your question please remember to accept the answer